# OpenGL changing light position with mouse

Tags: opengl, lighting

I'm trying to change light position at the click and drag of a mouse. I am doing this by disabling the current light, redefining another light using the new coordinates, and enabling the new one and switching back and forth. However, it only works the first time (the values are not getting reassigned). Is it not possible to define a GL_LIGHT more than once?

```
void changeLight()
{
    if (currentLight == 0){
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, black_color);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, initial_light_pos);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_light);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light_color);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        currentLight = 1;
    }
    else{
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
        glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, black_color);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, initial_light_pos);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_light);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_color);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        currentLight = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the switching between the 2 lights, why not just change the position of the light?